# C++ 3d array - dynamic memory allocation aligned in one line

Tags: c++, c, arrays, memory, allocation

i have a quite weird question which probably has no practical use but the answers bothers me a lot. I tried to mess around today a little bit with arrays and how they are allocated in memory using this code: (Compiler Xcode 4 btw, 4 byte integer)

```
int ***c;
int size_x = 0;
int size_y = 0;
int size_z = 0;

cout << "Enter x: " << endl;
cin >> size_x;
cout << "Enter y: " << endl;
cin >> size_y;
cout << "Enter z: " << endl;
cin >> size_z;

c = new int**[size_x];
for (int i = 0; i < size_x; ++i) {
    *(c+i) = new int*[size_y];
    for (int j = 0; j < size_y; ++j) {
        *(*(c+i)+j) = new int[size_z];
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < size_x; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < size_y; ++j) {
        for (int k = 0; k < size_z; ++k) {
            cout << (*(*(c+i)+j)+k) << endl;
            //cout << &c[i][j][k] << endl;
        }
    }
}

delete [] c;
```

When i enter now: 3, 2 and 4 i get the following output in the console:

0x100100a60
0x100100a64
0x100100a68
0x100100a6c
0x100100a70
0x100100a74
0x100100a78
0x100100a7c
0x100100a90
0x100100a94
0x100100a98
0x100100a9c
0x100100aa0
0x100100aa4
0x100100aa8
0x100100aac
0x100100ac0
0x100100ac4
0x100100ac8
0x100100acc
0x100100ad0
0x100100ad4
0x100100ad8
0x100100adc

What my question is now, if we look at the output, than we see that mostly, the memory is aligned every 4 bytes but sometimes we see a bigger step like from 0x100100a7c to
0x100100a90 .

Is this normal and how can i prevent this? Why is this? Is there a possibility to force c to align my memory as a constant line? (I'm not native english so sorry for that but i don't know how to say it better)

Its just for general understanding :-)

Thank u!

P.S. is it enough to use delete [] once btw or do i have to go through each of the 3 memory blocks and delete [] there the whole array? EDIT:

I delete memory now like this and it works pretty good:

```
cout << "Free Memory" << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < m_sx; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m_sy; ++j) {
        delete [] m_array[i][j];
        //delete [] (*(*(m_array)+j)+k);
    }
    delete [] m_array[i];
}

delete [] m_array, m_array = NULL;
```

Comment: I added a C++ tag. Should I also remove the C tag, or do you really want to have a C answer, too? Mondern C and C++ are quite different on how you can implement multidimensionnal arrays.

Comment: This has a practical use actually, by removing indirection and helping cache.

Comment: By the way, instead of using `new[]` and `delete[]` to allocate an array you would be better off directly using a `vector` ;)

Comment: Every `new[]` needs a `delete[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not that your memory isn't aligned ... the requirement by the C++ specification for a call to `new` and `new[]` is that it passes back a pointer pointing to contiguous memory that is properly aligned for the platform and the size of the object requested.

Your problem is that you are not allocating the entire buffer for the array with a single call to `new[]`, but rather with multiple calls to `new[]`.  Therefore while each call to `new` will return aligned and contiguous memory, the multiple calls to `new[]` are not required to return memory buffers that themselves are contiguously allocated.  For example, each call to `new[]` returns aligned memory, but as you noted, there can be "gaps" in the start of each memory array that `new` returns.  The reason for these "gaps" can have multiple reasons, and really depends on how the underlying OS is allocating memory for your program.

If you do not want to have any "gaps" in each array, then you will need to allocate the entire buffer with a single call to `new`.

Finally, to answer your question about `delete[]`, yes, because you did not allocate the entire memory buffer with a single call to `new[]`, you cannot delete your array with a single call to `delete[]`.  Every call to `new[]` must be paired with a call to `delete[]` since those were separate memory allocations.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. Makes a lot of sense and clears things out for me.. I wrote now above how I delete the memory.It seems to work fine. When i allocate memory right after it the same space gets used.

Comment: BTW, don't do `delete [] m_array, m_array = NULL;` in your last line ... the comma does not create a "sequence point" per the C++ spec, therefore depending on how the compiler decides to order the operations, you could end up with a huge memory leak as the compiler decides to reverse the operations and assign `NULL` to m_array and then call `delete []` on the now `NULL` pointer.  You will want to make those two separate statements by separating them with a semi-colon.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this is normal. The memory is *aligned*, btw., it's just not *contiguous* because subsequent calls to `new` do not make this guarantee. And yes, you can allocate the entire 3-d array in a single, contiguous buffer:

```
int *A = new int[size_x * size_y * size_z];
```

or, safer

```
std::vector<int> A(size_x * size_y * size_z);
```

and then index it with

```
int element = A[i * size_z * size_y + j * size_z + k]
```

to get the element at `(i,j,k)`.

This is, in fact, very useful, as it gives you multidimensional arrays with little overhead, preserving [locality of reference](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Locality_of_reference) and preventing indirection. Also, the error handling for this allocation scheme is much simpler so you run less of a risk of memory leaks. Any good matrix library will be implemented this way. For C++, that includes [Boost.MultiArray](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/multi_array%20Did).

As for deallocation: yes, you need multiple calls to `delete[]` in your present scheme.

Comment: is the first one also faster? i can image because the system doesn't have to jump around so much right?

Comment: @MarkusPfundstein: for many operations, yes. That's what I mean by locality of reference.

Answer (score 4):

Heres a routine which allocates the 3D array of dimension N1 x N2 x N3 in contiguous memory space while allowing you the a[i][j][k] syntax for operator access.  The array is dynamic but continuous so it's a huge plus over the vector<> approach and loops of new[] calls.

```
template <class T> T ***Create3D(int N1, int N2, int N3)
{
    T *** array = new T ** [N1];

    array[0] = new T * [N1*N2];

    array[0][0] = new T [N1*N2*N3];

    int i,j,k;

    for( i = 0; i < N1; i++) {

        if (i < N1 -1 ) {

            array[0][(i+1)*N2] = &(array[0][0][(i+1)*N3*N2]);

            array[i+1] = &(array[0][(i+1)*N2]);

        }

        for( j = 0; j < N2; j++) {     
            if (j > 0) array[i][j] = array[i][j-1] + N3;
        }

    }

    cout << endl;
    return array;
};

template <class T> void Delete3D(T ***array) {
    delete[] array[0][0]; 
    delete[] array[0];
    delete[] array;
};
```

And later in your implementation routine...

```
int *** array3d;
int N1=4, N2=3, N3=2;

int elementNumber = 0;

array3d = Create3D<int>(N1,N2,N3);

cout << "{" << endl;
for (i=0; i<N1; i++) {
    cout << "{";
    for (j=0; j<N2; j++) {
        cout << "{";
        for (k=0; k<N3; k++) {
            array3d[i][j][k] = elementNumber++;
            cout << setw(4) << array3d[i][j][k] << " ";
        }
        cout << "}";
    }
    cout << "}";
    cout << endl ;
}
cout << "}" << endl;

Delete3D(array3d);
```

Gives the output:

```
{
{{   0    1 }{   2    3 }{   4    5 }}
{{   6    7 }{   8    9 }{  10   11 }}
{{  12   13 }{  14   15 }{  16   17 }}
{{  18   19 }{  20   21 }{  22   23 }}
}
```

Comment: This is also equivalent to larsman's answer above, where the array is allocated as `int * A = new int[N1*N2*N3]` and accessed as `val = A[i*N2*N3 + j*N3 + k]`. But here bc of all the pointers-to-pointers you can use `val = array3d[i][j][k]`. To obtain the equivalent `int *` type reference to the array, one would do `int * A = array3d[0][0]`.

Answer (score 3):

Since this is tagged C, here is also a C answer. Since C99 multidimensional arrays can be handled quite efficiently, even if the sizes are dynamic:

```
double c[size_x][size_y][size_z];
```

This allocates the matrix contiguously on the stack. Matrix elements are accessed by `c[i][j][k]` and the compiler does all the indexing arithmetic for you. If you fear that this could lead to SO, you can easily call `malloc` with it:

```
double (*c)[size_y][size_z] = malloc(sizeof(double[size_x][size_y][size_z]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is normal.
You allocate data row by row; The only thing you can be sure is that data will be contiguous on each row.